# Secondary Facebook email added not by me

Tags: facebook

I have a secondary email on my page that I did not add; it is a @facebook.com address. Does Facebook add this and what determines the name tied to it?

Answer (score 3):

Your @facebook.com email is an optional email address for your Facebook account, and is based on your username. Email messages that are sent to your @facebook.com email address will be forwarded to the primary email on your Facebook account.

https://www.facebook.com/help/224049364288051

Comment: So this @facebook address is created automatically when you sign up for Facebook?

Comment: Yes, everyone got one. There was a kerfuffle a couple of years ago when they added it and then changed it to your primary email address on your Facebook profile. They changed that policy and de-emphasized the address, but they still exist.